# Overlapping bars in horizontal Bar graph

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I am generating horizontal bar graphs using mathplotlib from
SO: [How to plot multiple horizontal bars in one chart with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201386/how-to-plot-multiple-horizontal-bars-in-one-chart-with-matplotlib). The problem is when I have more than 2 horizontal bars, the bars are getting overlapped. Not sure, what I am doing wrong.
Here is the following graph code

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pandas.DataFrame(dict(graph=['q1','q2','q3' , 'q4','q5',' q6'],
                           n=[3, 5, 2,3 ,5 , 2], m=[6, 1, 3, 6 , 1 , 3])) 

ind = np.arange(len(df))
width = 0.4
opacity = 0.4
fig, ax = plt.subplots()


ax.barh(ind, df.n, width, alpha=opacity, color='r', label='Existing')
ax.barh(ind + width, df.m, width, alpha=opacity,color='b', label='Community')
ax.barh(ind + 2* width, df.m, width, alpha=opacity,color='g', label='Robust')

ax.set(yticks=ind + width , yticklabels=df.graph, ylim=[2*width - 1, len(df)])
ax.legend()



#plt.xlabel('Queries')
plt.xlabel('Precesion')
plt.title('Precesion for these  queries')

plt.show()
```

Currently, the graph looks like this 
[image: Overlapped bars in Graph]

Answer (score 2):

You set the width of the bars to 0.4, but you have three bars in each group.  That means the width of each group is 1.2.  But you set the ticks only 1 unit apart, so your bars don't fit into the spaces.

Since you are using pandas, you don't really need to do all that.  Just do `df.plot(kind='barh')` and you will get a horizontal bar chart of the dataframe data.  You can tweak the display colors, etc., by using various paramters to `plot` that you can find in the documentation.  (If you want the "graph" column to be used as y-axis labels, set it as the index: `df.set_index('graph').plot(kind='barh')`)

(Using `df.plot` will give a barplot with only two bars per group, since your DataFrame has only two numeric columns.  In your example, you plotted column `m` twice, which doesn't seem very useful.  If you really want to do that, you could add a duplicate column into the DataFrame.)

Comment: the only problem is I am not able to name the elements in yaxis side. its just enumerating.  http://imgur.com/myoXtQv  instead of 0,1,2 in yaxis I need to add custom names. I am not able to find that in documentation on how to do that. any ideas ?

Comment: @Rahul: If you set the index it will automatically be used for the labels.  Do `df.set_index('graph').plot(kind='barh')`.

Comment: nah, thats not exactly working for me. if I want the labels to be q1 , q2 and q3 on the yaxis. Then pandas is expecting to values from q1. which is not the case. all I want is to label them and not enumerate it.

Comment: @Rahul: I don't quite understand what you're saying, but you can set the tick labels with something like `pyplot.gca().yaxis.set_ticklabels(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])`.  You can find plenty of information about how to do this sort of thing by googling "matplotlib tick labels" or the like.

Answer (score 1):

`ax=df.plot.barh(width=0.85,figsize=(15,15))`

adjust width(should be less than 1 otherwise overlaps) and figsize to get the best and clear view of bars. Because if the figure is bigger you can have a clear and bigger view of bars which is the ultimate goal.