# How can I solve my show number overlap my bar-chart when I using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

[image]

And this is my code below :

```
def generate_bar_chart(self, x_data, y_data, legend, pic_name):

        n = len(x_data)

        plt.bar(range(n), y_data, align='center', color='steelblue', alpha=0.8, label=legend)

        plt.xticks(range(n), x_data, rotation=90)

        for x, y in enumerate(y_data):
            plt.text(x, y+100, '%s' % round(y, 1), ha='center', rotation=90, alpha=0.8)
        plt.grid(axis='y', linestyle='-', alpha=0.8)
        plt.legend()
        plt.tight_layout()
        pic_file = os.path.join(self.pic_path, pic_name)
        plt.savefig(pic_file)
        plt.close()
```

mayber there something wrong with enumerate() and plt.text, please give me some advice, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would update 2 things in how you are plotting this:

1. set the text alignment - `verticalalignment='bottom'` (or the shorthand `va`), which makes the label placement insensitive to the label length.
2. use the `plt.annotate` instead of `plt.text`.  For your use case, the parameters are very similar, but it is also robust to both the scale of the data and the current zoom level.

The `xytext=(0,5)` makes the text start in the center of your bar, and 5 points above it (also include textcoords='offset points').

```
for x, y in enumerate(y_data):
    plt.annotate('%s' % round(y, 1), xy=(x, y), 
        xytext=(0, 5), textcoords='offset points',
        va='bottom', ha='center', rotation=90)
```

For reference, to just achieve #1 can be done with `plt.text`:

```
for x, y in enumerate(y_data):
    plt.text(x, y+300, '%s' % round(y, 1), ha='center',
        va='bottom', rotation=90, alpha=0.8)
```

Comment: It is woks well, thanks so much, Futher, there multiple horizontal bars in one chart, how can I add number label above bars? like the answer of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201386/how-to-plot-multiple-horizontal-bars-in-one-chart-with-matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201386/how-to-plot-multiple-horizontal-bars-in-one-chart-with-matplotlib), xytext(0,5),0 must be change?

Comment: maybe I should change the position of x,y as xy=(y,x)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the numbers to be printed above the bars ? If so, then just modify the offset for y in the call to text(). Currently you add 100, but keep in mind this is expressed in axis coordinates, so 100 is still a small value considering the total range of your y axis. Try 500 for example.
In order to set a similar offset to all bars, you have to define your offset from a relative point of view. You could try `1.15 * y` instead of `y+100` in the text() call.

Comment: I have question again, different number may be set different offset. As above, the max number is 18129 and offset set 2000 is well, but if the max number is 100 the offset will be smaller than 2000, maybe 10 is enough. So how can I set fixed offset for different?