# Horizontal bar plot with multiple bars per ytick

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm not quite understanding how you're supposed to pass in parameters to create a horizontal bar plot in matplotlib. I'm just trying to imitate what i see on this sample code... https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-bar-chart/

As well as what I see in this stackoverflow post
[How to plot multiple horizontal bars in one chart with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201386/how-to-plot-multiple-horizontal-bars-in-one-chart-with-matplotlib)

Right now my code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
x_locs = np.arange(len(total_vals))
t_label_lst = ['Digital Learning Apps', 'News, Events, Daily', 'News on School Events', 'STEM Extracurriculars & School Programs', 'Hiring, STEM Workforce', 'Women in STEM', 'Activities and Projects Outside of the Classroom', 'Ambiguous', 'Ambiguous, STEM in College', 'Next Generation of Engineers', 'News, Events, Daily', 'Educational Policy and Higher Education, Reform', 'STEM Activities, Building, Arts, and Design', 'Engaging students with STEM using programming and robotics', 'Black Leaders in STEM', 'Next Generation of Engineers', 'Ambiguous', 'Astronomy, NASA', 'STEM workshops and summer camps', 'Competitions, Team Credit', 'Ambiguous, Technology Hashtags', 'Google Education', 'Good Job Today! Crediting Daily Activities and Work', 'Engaging students with STEM using programming and robotics', 'Environmental Science', 'Teachers, Public Schools In STEM', 'Ambiguous', 'Edtech Companies', 'Ambiguous, PHD Conversation', 'Ambiguous', 'Engaging students with STEM using programming and robotics', 'Ambiguous, Virtual Reality and Personalized learning mention', 'Ambiguous', 'Ambiguous', 'Ambiguous, #Autism hashtag has disproportionate weight']

print(x_locs)
total_vals = [23668, 13186, 10752, 10002, 9558, 9126, 8138, 7389, 7006, 6965, 6859, 6621, 6538, 5700, 5110, 5069, 4419, 4025, 3943, 3866, 3761, 3697, 3543, 3294, 3067, 2928, 2511, 2491, 2353, 2312, 2229, 2175, 2021, 1921, 1787]
positive_vals = [9941, 9306, 7595, 5935, 5913, 7488, 5258, 4905, 4026, 5242, 5557, 3225, 3530, 3055, 3300, 3503, 2461, 2199, 2074, 2379, 1665, 2274, 2250, 1674, 1523, 1533, 1241, 859, 1504, 1419, 1132, 1082, 805, 753, 580]
neutral_vals = [13727, 3880, 3157, 4067, 3645, 1638, 2880, 2484, 2980, 1723, 1302, 3396, 3008, 2645, 1810, 1566, 1958, 1826, 1869, 1487, 2096, 1423, 1293, 1620, 1544, 1395, 1270, 1632, 849, 893, 1097, 1093, 1216, 1168, 1207]

rects1 = ax.barh(x_locs, total_vals, width=.15, color='r', label="total tweet count")
# rects2 = ax.barh(positive_vals, width=.2, color = 'b', label="positive tweet count")
# rects3 = ax.barh(neutral_vals, width=.2, color='yellow', label="neutral tweet count")
ax.set(yticks=x_locs, yticklabels=t_label_lst, ylim=[0, len(x_locs)])
plt.show()
```

But this just causes the program to crash with the following error message: "TypeError: barh() got multiple values for argument 'width'" I'm not even sure why this error is coming up if I'm setting the width parameter to .15.

total_vals contains 35 counts, or frequencies that I'm trying to plot in the x axis. Like these are the values that I'm trying to make my bars reflect in terms of height. positive_vals and neutral_vals also contain 35 counts.

x_locs is a variable I created based on what I saw in the sample code, but that's just supposed to be the numbers 0-34. That's just supposed to indicate each of the 35 bars I'm trying to show.

What's also getting me confused is what happens when i remove x_locs. So if I just do

```
 rects1 = ax.barh(total_vals, width=.15, color='r', label="total tweet count")
```

I get this matplotlib graph, which seems to plot my "width" parameter on the x axis of the graph/makes the width parameter the limit of the x axis.

[image: graph in which the x axis is actually the width parameter. At least my yticks are correct]

My yticks seem like they're actually displaying correctly in the order that they should be going at least, but it appears that the width is what's gettting plotted or measured on the x axis... and clearly, the graph is empty.

I get that my yticklabels are hideously long right now and I merely uploaded this code just so that it could be reproducible.

I'm not really certain at this point what the "y" parameter is actually supposed to indicate. The documentation says "the y coordinates of each bar." I initially was thinking that the y parameter was just supposed to be the counts I wanted to show, but then I saw that the "left" parameter is "the x coordinates of the left sides of the bars."

So I changed my code to

```
rects1 = ax.barh(y=x_locs, left=total_vals, width=.15, color='r', label="total tweet count")
```

And this changed the y axis correctly, but it still gave me an empty graph. I don't know what's happening to my counts/bars and why they're not showing at all.

[image: yet another empty matplotlib graph but at least the x axis is correct now]

How do I actually get the bars to show? I just have some clear confusion about how the parameters actually work for these horizontal bar graphs.

Comment: To be clear, you expect a chart where the bars for each tick are side by side, as opposed to stacked, right?

Comment: Yes, the bars should be side by side and not stacked. A given ytick/label like the one at the bottom, "digital learning apps," should have 3 bars each beneath each other.

Comment: I'm looking for the barplot in this stackoverflow post (though I think I linked this in the original question... maybe I didn't) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201386/how-to-plot-multiple-horizontal-bars-in-one-chart-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were actually really close with your code; you just had some confusion about the parameters of `barh`.

First, let's clarify the required arguments are.

The first positional argument is `y`, which refers to the y-coordinates of *each category*. Accordingly, `x_locs` is a misnomer. These can be created easily, in running order: the first category at `y=0`, the second at `y=1` and so on.

Next, you pass a variable like `total_vals`, but also `width`, and get an error.

Consider that a bar is defined by two aspects, *position* and *size*. Since all the bars are aligned with the left spine of the plot, their x-coordinates are the same, and they will be defined solely by their y-coordinates, which we have already done.

For a bar plot, we generally want one dimension to be dynamic (the one which represents some quantity), and the other to be the same for all bars. The one that is the same is `height`, since it is equal to the vertical size of the bar.

The other, dynamic, dimension, then, is `width`, and it is `width` that represents `total_vals`, `positive_vals` and `negative_vals`. Accordingly, you got that error because you were trying to specify how long each bar should be *twice*.

Now, let's go back to `y_locs`. Remember that we want 3 bars for each tick, *side-by-side*. This is equivalent to saying that we want each "class" of bar (`total`, `negative` and `positive`) to be adjusted slightly, otherwise they would overlap.

For example, we could have the bars for `negative` remain at the positions specified by `y_loc`, the ones for `positive` shifted downwards by 10 pixels, and the ones for `total` by 20. This is an implementation detail; what is important is that we recognise the *need* for such an offset.

Putting all this together, we get:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 10))

t_label_lst = ['Digital Learning Apps', 'News, Events, Daily', 'News on School Events', 'STEM Extracurriculars & School Programs', 'Hiring, STEM Workforce', 'Women in STEM', 'Activities and Projects Outside of the Classroom', 'Ambiguous', 'Ambiguous, STEM in College', 'Next Generation of Engineers', 'News, Events, Daily', 'Educational Policy and Higher Education, Reform', 'STEM Activities, Building, Arts, and Design', 'Engaging students with STEM using programming and robotics', 'Black Leaders in STEM', 'Next Generation of Engineers', 'Ambiguous', 'Astronomy, NASA', 'STEM workshops and summer camps', 'Competitions, Team Credit', 'Ambiguous, Technology Hashtags', 'Google Education', 'Good Job Today! Crediting Daily Activities and Work', 'Engaging students with STEM using programming and robotics', 'Environmental Science', 'Teachers, Public Schools In STEM', 'Ambiguous', 'Edtech Companies', 'Ambiguous, PHD Conversation', 'Ambiguous', 'Engaging students with STEM using programming and robotics', 'Ambiguous, Virtual Reality and Personalized learning mention', 'Ambiguous', 'Ambiguous', 'Ambiguous, #Autism hashtag has disproportionate weight']

total_vals = [23668, 13186, 10752, 10002, 9558, 9126, 8138, 7389, 7006, 6965, 6859, 6621, 6538, 5700, 5110, 5069, 4419, 4025, 3943, 3866, 3761, 3697, 3543, 3294, 3067, 2928, 2511, 2491, 2353, 2312, 2229, 2175, 2021, 1921, 1787]
positive_vals = [9941, 9306, 7595, 5935, 5913, 7488, 5258, 4905, 4026, 5242, 5557, 3225, 3530, 3055, 3300, 3503, 2461, 2199, 2074, 2379, 1665, 2274, 2250, 1674, 1523, 1533, 1241, 859, 1504, 1419, 1132, 1082, 805, 753, 580]
neutral_vals = [13727, 3880, 3157, 4067, 3645, 1638, 2880, 2484, 2980, 1723, 1302, 3396, 3008, 2645, 1810, 1566, 1958, 1826, 1869, 1487, 2096, 1423, 1293, 1620, 1544, 1395, 1270, 1632, 849, 893, 1097, 1093, 1216, 1168, 1207]

bar_size = 0.25
padding = 0.25

y_locs = np.arange(len(total_vals)) * (bar_size * 3 + padding)

rects1 = ax.barh(y_locs, total_vals, align='edge', height=bar_size, color='r', label="total tweet count")
rects2 = ax.barh(y_locs + bar_size, positive_vals, align='edge', height=bar_size, color='b', label="positive tweet count")
rects3 = ax.barh(y_locs + 2 * bar_size, neutral_vals, align='edge', height=bar_size, color='yellow', label="neutral tweet count")
ax.set(yticks=x_locs, yticklabels=t_label_lst, ylim=[0 - padding, len(x_locs)])
```

[image: Output]

Comment: ```NameError: name 'x_locs' is not defined```. Should that have been ```y_locs```?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simples answer is just change **width** into **height**, since it's a vertical graph.