# Bar charts to be displayed Horizontal for different dataframes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I need to plot various bar graphs through various dataframes, I have around 13 different dataframe on which i need to plot graph. I have successfully done that but graph are positioned vertically, I need to position them horizontally instead of vertically.

I have tried to plot them by using matplotlib. But not able to position them  horizontally.

```
plt.title("Circle Wise Sites", fontsize="10")
plt.bar(x,y,width=0.5, color=("b"))
#Plt.bar(x,y, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, *, align='center', data=None)
plt.xlabel("Circle",fontsize="10" )
plt.ylabel("Pass (%)",fontsize="10")
plt.tick_params(axis='x',which='major',labelsize=8)
plt.tick_params(axis='y',which='major',labelsize=8)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='green')
plt.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
for i, val in enumerate(df_Merge_cir['Pass'].values):
    plt.text(i, val, float(val), horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='bottom', fontdict={'fontweight':500, 'size':10})


plt.show()



# Assam Plot
plt2.title("Assam DCEM States", fontsize="10")
plt2.bar(x1,y1,width=0.3, color=("g"))
plt2.xlabel("Zone",fontsize="10" )
plt2.ylabel("Pass (%)",fontsize="10")
plt2.tick_params(axis='x',which='major',labelsize=8)
plt2.tick_params(axis='y',which='major',labelsize=8)
plt2.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt2.minorticks_on()
plt2.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='green')
plt2.grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
for i, val in enumerate(df_Merge_Assam['Pass'].values):
    plt2.text(i, val, float(val), horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='bottom', fontdict={'fontweight':500, 'size':10})

    plt2.show()
```

Need bar chart to be positioned horizontally.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201386/how-to-plot-multiple-horizontal-bars-in-one-chart-with-matplotlib

Comment: No, I have different question, Need to position them horizontally.

Comment: It is unclear whether you want the *bars* to be horizontal, or whether you want multiple subplots in a line

Comment: Hi, Multiple subplots in a line but each subplot has different Dateframe.